# Count amount of times an id appears in column store in new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks as following:

```
    ID  
    1
    1
    1
    2
    2
    3
    3
    3
    4
```

Desired result I want to achieve

```
    ID  Count
    1   3
    1   3
    1   3
    2   2
    2   2
    3   3
    3   3
    3   3
    4   1
```

I tried to work with the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Count FROM table
```

But didn't work, is there another solution? I want to store it in another column

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: I'm using mysql

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: Note that you appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, which will likely prove problematic in due course.

Answer (score 5):

Most of DBMS's supports *window* function, so you can use :

```
SELECT t.ID, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id) AS Count 
FROM table t;
```

You can also use *correlated* subquery :

```
SELECT t.id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id) AS Count 
FROM table t
```

Comment: Not able to obtain the right output, can it be possible that WHERE clauses appearing later in the query influence the counts?

Comment: . . . `Where` clause shrink your data. So that possibility would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

If your MySql version does not allow window functions then join the table to a query that returns the counters for each `id`:

```
select t.id, g.counter
from tablename t inner join (
  select id, count(*) counter
  from tablename
  group by id
) g on g.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is

Select ID, count(ID) from Table group by ID

Comment: OP wants all rows returned, plus a count column.

Answer (score 0):

A possible slightly expensive solution, in mysql, would be

```
select @id:=id as id,(select count(*) from table where id=@id) as count from table;
```